# Gap between mouse on screen and JPanel on Dragndrop

Tags: java, user-interface, jpanel

I use JPanel to draw a square on the screen. 
When I use MouseDragged it works fine and goes wherever I want, almost. Each time I click on the square, the square automatically moves and the top left corner goes right under the mouse.
How should I do so that the square doesn't replace itself and stays right under the mouse ?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Keep an account of the difference between `top-left` coordinates of Component which you are
moving and `mousePressed` location.
And when you get new position, just subtract that difference to it.
Here I have tried to explain it through coding. Let `myJPanel` be the component you want to
move. Then here is the `MouseAdapter` that can work for you. New position is stored in
`newPosition` variable.

```
new MouseAdapter(){
    int diffx = 0, diffy = 0;
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        Point topLeft = myJPanel.getLocation();
        Point mouseDn = e.getPoint();
        diffx = mouseDn.x - topLeft.x;
        diffy = mouseDn.y - topLeft.y;
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        Point mouseDr = e.getPoint();
        int newX = mouseDr.x - diffx;
        int newY = mouseDr.y - diffy;
        Point newPosition = new Point(newX, newY);
    }
};
```